# Android Textview not Updating

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, textview

everyone.
I'm trying to make a basic tycoon game for Android
and I'm trying to increment the value of text-views every 5 seconds with a timer,
But the textview doesn't update.
Here's my code so far:

```
public class Town extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Timer timer;
TimerTask task;
TextView goldTV;
TextView woodTV;
TextView foodTV;
TextView stoneTV;
TextView cashTV;
int gold = 20;
int wood = 20;
int food = 20;
int stone = 20;
int cash = 200;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_town);
    goldTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    woodTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    foodTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    stoneTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
    cashTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
    timer = new Timer();
    task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            gold++;
            goldTV.setText(gold);
            try {
                this.wait(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
            }
        }

    };
}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a TimerTask should be used with a Timer object. in your code you never run the task.

**edit:**
try this instead:

```
goldTV.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                gold++;
                goldTV.setText(gold+"");
                goldTV.postDelayed(this,2000);
            }
        }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `run()` method

```
@Override
public void run() {
          gold++;
          goldTV.setText(gold);

          try {
                this.wait(2000);
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e){

          }
}
```

You're calling `setText(int resId)` instead of `setText(CharSequence c);`

To display the actual integer `gold`,  convert it from `int` to `String`

```
String goldStr = String.valueOf(gold);

goldTV.setText(goldStr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are changing the text on something other than the UI thread. Better is to run it on the UI thread. Plus you should convert your number into a string, or else Android will think you are looking for a resource id. Put them both together, and...

```
task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        gold++;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
            goldTV.setText(""+gold);
           }
        });
        try {
            this.wait(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
    }

};
```

Or even better, you could use a handler, like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable task=new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      handler.postDelayed(this,5000);
      goldTV.setText(""+gold);
   }
});
handler.postDelayed(task,5000);
```